# Iterate list while assigning new values to it

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a python code that changes the list while iterating. Why is it iterating 5 times? I expect it should iterate according to the new list.

what is "`for i in l`" doing underneath? why it has nothing to do with l while iteration?

if `l` is not changed, why after loop it is empty?

```
cnt = 4
def print_list():
    global cnt
    l=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    for i in l:  # why it iterates 5 times? 
        print "iteration ", i 
        l = range(1, cnt)  # new assignment
        print l 
        cnt-=1
    print "after loop l is ", l # after loop, l is empty
```

Print result:

```
iteration  1
[1, 2, 3]
iteration  2
[1, 2]
iteration  3
[1]
iteration  4
[]
iteration  5
[]
after loop l is []
```

EDIT: from the answers below, now i understand:

1. in python, `l` is referring to a different object after assignment;
2. original object referred at very beginning by `l` does not get changed.

Comment: "I have a python code that changes the list while iteration" - ***don't do that***. Also, you're not changing the list. You're changing the `l` variable, but the loop doesn't pay any attention to that any more.

Comment: Actually changing the list in python while iterating over it is acceptable if you are not changing it size and if you know what you are doing.

Comment: @user2357112, if i am not changing l, why after loop it is empty?

Comment: @pepero you're confusing the list itself with the name that refers to it. The sequence `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` that resides in memory is not modified by anything you do in this code. However, the name `l` is reassigned to refer to a *different* and empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the for loop, you are reassigning the variable of `l` to a new list – but *not* changing the original `l` over which you are still iterating.

Here's a more concise example demonstrating this situation, where `l` is now called `my_object`, and where `my_object` begins as a `list` and is reassigned to meaningless strings that do not affect the iteration:

```
random_things = [
    "dog", "cat", "fish", "bird", "bug"
]

my_object = xrange(len(random_things))
orig_id = id(my_object)
for i in my_object:
    if i == 0:
        first_iter_id = id(my_object)
    print orig_id == id(my_object),

    # At this point, my_object is
    # reassigned and has no influence on
    # the my_object that is be iterated over
    my_object = random_things[i]
    print i, my_object

print "Original ID == FirstIter ID? {0}".format(orig_id == first_iter_id)
print "Original ID == LastIter ID? {0}".format(orig_id == id(my_object))
```

**Output:**

```
True 0 dog
False 1 cat
False 2 fish
False 3 bird
False 4 bug
Original ID == FirstIter ID? True
Original ID == LastIter ID? False
```

In this example, you can see how the `id` of `my_object` on the first iteration is still equal to the original `id` of `my_object`; but afterwards, you reassign `my_object`, and it references a new object in memory.

*Just because we reassign the name of `my_object` to a new object in memory does not mean we mutate the value of the original object we are still iterating over.*

To see this, notice how `first_iter_id` is equal to `orig_id` after the loop completes – this is becasue `first_iter_id` was assigned before we overwrote `my_object` on that first iteration.

Comment: I'd recommend cutting out the fluff from the code in the answer, you can demonstrate the problem in a much shorter loop

Comment: @RyanHaining I agree, and will simplify the example when I get additional time. I hope the OP will find this informative in the interim.

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually changing the list by assigning

```
l = range(1, cnt)
```

If you studied C type languages before, this assignment behaves like another definition in another scope. Also the list is cached before the for loop starts running to avoid repetition. For example,

```
for i in range(10):
    #pass
```

does not create a `range(10)` list ten times. The first one is stored so it can be used throughout the iteration.

If you really want to alter the list you have to do operations that does not create a new list in memory. Such as,

```
l.append()
l.remove()
l.pop()
l[x] = y
```

you can try these yourself on your loop and find out the result.